# Accent Insensitive Search in Grails - Create Criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

is there an easy way how to search accent insensitive in Grails? I have a create criteria builder with ilike (which is for case insensitive search) but I need accent insensitive. Like neglect accent in characters like á ů ä ü. These characters should fit in search when user tipes a u a u.

Thanks,
Mateo

Comment: I would suggest using a regex to strip all accents before passing it to a criteria.

Comment: The thing is that the special characters are stored in MySQL therefore stripping the accents before would not help

Answer (score 2):

The solution is on DB level:

- setting database collation to `utf8_general_ci` does the job.
- the `_ci` suffix of collation means CASE INSENSITIVE which is actually also accent insensitive.

Comment: Where i should put that?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE  'efarma' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;`